# Extjs: How to define a working layout for a custom menu

Tags: extjs, menu, height, customization

**ExtJS**:
I have a button where I want to associate a menu. I want to define the layout of the menu myself, and from what I gather from the [documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.menu.Menu), the layout can be specified directly.

**Button + menu**:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',        
    menu: {
        xtype: 'menu',
        plain: true,
        layout: 'fit',          
        height: 300,
        width: 200,
        items:
        [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'vbox',
                layoutConfig: {
                    align: 'stretch',
                    pack: 'start'
                },
                items:
                [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        text: 'Label1'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        text: 'Label2'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'textfield'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    menuAlign: 'bl-tl',
    text: 'Button'
}
```

The result has zero height, but If I change the `xtype: 'menu'` to `xtype: 'panel'` and put it inside an `Ext.Window`, then it works like I want it too.

**Question**: How should I customize the menu to get what I want with the correct height?

Comment: Wait, are you saying you want a menu INSIDE a button? Or do you mean you want a menu triggered by a button click?

Comment: **@Jere:** I just want the menu to be triggered by clicking the button. Thanks for clearing that one out ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the same question at the *Sencha* forums and got the following help:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?116614-How-to-define-a-working-layout-for-a-custom-menu

The key points for me was to *not* set any layout or size attributes on the menu, but instead do it on the nested container. The `forceLayout: true` attribute might also have helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, using the your answer and the forum post, in my case I am passing a menu into a button.  This is what I came up with in Ext 4.0.2 based on the above.   Just thought I would post in case anyone comes to visit later, or in case the sencha forums are ever down.

First, I give the menu items an **anchor** and a **height**.  Note that home_menu is simply a regular array.

```
home_menu.push({
   text:name,
   value:id,
   scope:this,
   anchor:'100%',
   height:30,
   handler:function(o,e)
    {
       //...                         
    }});
```

Then, the important configs for the menu itself are **forceLayout** and **autoHeight**:

```
h_btn.menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu',
{
    items:home_menu
    ,forceLayout: true 
    ,autoHeight:true     //so it listens to the height of the items
});
```